# Ruby: find where global variable is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Some gem in my tests sets `$stdout` to `dev/null`. Is there a way to raise an error whenever `$stdout` is changed? Or is there some other way to track what changes it?

Update: For anyone who might have similar issue - the problem was that `quietly` and `silence_stream` methods of ActiveSupport are not thread safe. In this case `activerecord-session_store` is the offending gem, see https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/pull/22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  if $stdout != STDOUT
    STDOUT.puts "$stdout changed at #{file}:#{line}"
    exit
  end
}
```

Hmm. I guess that would actually be the line after the change, technically... If you care, you can remember the previous file/line in each trace step, and print that instead.

Comment: I am not sure I was getting correct file or line either way, but caller_locations helped to track down offending method. Thanks!